# Can someone explain why 玩儿 is used in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters

I am someone new to chinese, I am in chinese 3 honors. We are learning about traveling and had some questions about the use of 玩儿 in these sentences and why they are here!

今年夏天我们在西安玩儿了三天，在北京玩儿了一个星期 - This summer we spent three days in Xi'an and one week in Beijing

他们在北京一共玩儿了七天。- They spent a total of seven days in Beijing.

如果你想去中国玩儿，你就要办签证 - You need a visa if you want to go to China

Can someone break down the sentence structure to these sentences :)

Comment: 玩/玩儿 means "to play" like how one might play a game

Comment: But, why would you use it if you are talking about going to china or spending days in a country？

Comment: @我爱学校 It's because you want to have fun there(to play). 玩 generally means "to have fun" in this case. 玩 indicates the purpose of the trip - to have fun, instead of a business one.

Comment: its the difference between "going to china" and "going to china to play (have a good time)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

今年夏天我们在西安玩儿了三天，
This year in summer we spent three pleasant days in Xi An,
在北京玩儿了一个星期。
then another seven days enjoying the sights of Bei Jing.

他们在北京一共玩儿了七天。
In all they spent seven days enjoying Bei Jing.

如果你想去中国玩儿，你就要办签证。
If you would like to go on a trip to China, you need a visa.

There is a somewhat different view of "玩儿" in China, not fixated in play. The Chinese think nothing of saying, "I want to play with you." (我要跟你玩儿）

That always makes me smirk!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As a Chinese, I don't think so we need to play a lot of "玩儿“, the retroflex final is more useful in the north of china.